# Empty cell in Excel returns Null (Java, POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I wish to display the values from Excel. My issue is I am not sure why I am getting "null" as well.

[image]

Comment: Exactly as it is documented [Row.getCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-): "Get the cell representing a given column (logical cell) 0-based. If you ask for a cell that is not defined....you get a null.". See also: [Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells)

Comment: @Axel, thank you so much for your reply. If that is the case, I am getting more curious as to how it know when to stop reading the coloumn. In other words, why did it stop at 6th "null" and not print out a whole list of "Nulls" ? Really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Your `for (Row : Sheet)` simply reads only present rows. A modern `Excel` sheet can contain 2^20 rows each having 2^14 cells. To not need storing all those cells in the file, rows which are completely empty are not stored and so are `null` if tried to get. Also cells which are completely empty (no content, no style, no something) are not stored and so are `null`. So your sheet seems to contain 11 rows where at least one cell is not completely empty. First 5 rows have content in first cell. Rows 6 to 11 must have content or style or something in at least one other cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the cell *object*.  Do a null-check and access the *value* of the cell - something like this:

```
Cell cell = rowAmt.getCell(0);
if (cell != null) {
    System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
    /*
     * for numbers: cell.getNumericCellValue();
     * for booleans: cell.getBooleanCellValue();
     */
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It did the job ! Do you mind briefly explaining about that cell object ? Just would like to learn more about it. Thanks again !

Comment: [Here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) is a link to the documentation for the Cell interface.

If you haven't already, you should take a look at the link posted by @Axel Richter for examples provided by the POI team.